# Tooltip does not load in HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap tooltip button that should show a tooltip when I hover.However it does not work. I have followed many suggestions online about initialize tooltips on document load and it still won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Parent View</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
            Tooltip on top
        </button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            });
        </script>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the script inside the HTML BODY it's execute *before* jQuery has loaded at the end of the body, so jQuery `$` is undefined.

Move the script after jQuery, Bootstrap and Popper, or to the HTML HEAD tag.

**And,** make sure the Tooltip has a **title**.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My title">
        Tooltip on top
</button>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/2huMTgy7Q9

Comment: Didn't work for both 'In the HTML HEAD tag' and 'After  jQuery, Bootstrap and Popper'

Comment: Working now. Thank you so much.